# What version of a library does gradle use by default?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

I previously I had these dependancies defined in my gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb'
```

My (incorrect?) assumption was that gradle would just use the latest versions.

But some packages seemed to not be in the version gradle was using:
[image]

I changed my dependencies list to have specific versions like this and it solved the issue above:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.106'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.106'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.106'
```

So Im guess gradle was pulling the wrong version? What does it do if you don't specify a version and how do I see what version its using?

Comment: how about this? For sure https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.179
`compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.179'` is for `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient`
Another error maybe dependencies conflict. Try analize tool to define the conflict

Comment: Analyze is a gradle tool or intellij tool? It says it can't find them not that there is a conflict. Maybe I'm using a newer version of the library that doesn't have them?

Comment: `version: '1.11.179'` is latest version and it included them. Im not sure but could you try https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies ?